# using the value of an input in an sql query

Tags: php, sql

i am trying to show all employees that have mon_morn ='yes' in the ip_employee_availability table but i dont want the employee to be shown if they have requested time off which is stored in ip_employee_request and their requestDate is the same value as the date in my input e.g  if they have requested 2016-03-27 off  but they have mon_morn= 'yes' in the availability table i dont want them to show.

this is the input

```
<form action="mng_menu2.php" method="post">
    <input type='text' name='monday' id='date' value='2016-03-27'>
</form>
```

and this is the query

```
$sql = "SELECT e.employeeName FROM ip_employee_availability a
INNER JOIN ip_employee e ON a.employeeID = e.employeeID
INNER JOIN ip_employee_request r ON a.employeeID = r.employeeID
where mon_morn = 'yes' and requestDate <> $_POST['monday] ";

$myData= mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Comment: So what is your issue?

Comment: In what way is this code not working as expected?  Also, be aware that you have a glaring SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: its not identifying the value within the input

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: monday in /home/unn_w12014288/public_html/finalproject/mng_menu2.php on line 42

Comment: therefore the query isnt executing properly :\

Comment: Your issue is therefore not related to SQL whatsoever, only PHP, at least for now.
Try displaying $_POST['monday'] and fix this first. Don't you simply have a missing single quote after 'monday'?

Comment: i have just typed that accidentally sorry but no its still not working still says Undefined index: monday

Comment: all sorted thanks any way

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  I'm thinking `not exists` in this case:

```
SELECT e.employeeName
FROM ip_employee_availability a INNER JOIN
     ip_employee e
     ON a.employeeID = e.employeeID
WHERE a.mon_morn = 'yes' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM ip_employee_request r 
                  WHERE a.employeeID = r.employeeID AND
                        r.requestDate = $_POST['monday]
                 );
```

You can fix the potential SQL injection problem by using parameters instead of embedding user-input values in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

This is a PHP only question.
You need to understand why you get an "Undefined index: monday" exception before moving on.
Try the following

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['monday'])) {
   echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['monday']) . '!';
} else {
   echo 'Something went wrong.';
}
?>
```

Make that part work before trying to look at a potential SQL query issue.
You might find more information [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

In the meantime, regarding the SQL query: since you have an issue with the `$_POST['monday']` variable, have you tried replacing it with a static value, like `'2016-03-27'`? Does it work?